# Trying to add Minecraft to firewall but can't seem to find the location of the Java folder or javaw.exe

Tags: windows, java, firewall, minecraft

My firewall has blocked Minecraft, so I can't seem to play in multiplayer. So, I went to go add Minecraft as an allowed app for the firewall. Since I have java edition, other tutorials have been saying to allow 'javaw.exe'. However, this file isn't showing up in when I look through the list of apps/features I can allow through firewall. Apparently the default location of this file is supposed to be `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaw.exe` but I looked in both program files folders and can't seem to even find a folder named 'Java'

I don't know if this is why, but I'm on a new computer and the files (including Minecraft) were just copied from my old computer via USB, so perhaps this is why there is no 'Java' folder? But any way I can fix this, or do I have to find my old computer and copy the Java folder over again?

Also, the rest of minecraft (like minecraft launcher and stuff) is installed in a different folder than the default, but I looked in that folder and in the minecraft folder and didn't seem to find anything either...

Comment: The location of Java entirely depends on which version of Java you have installed.  You can [edit] your question to include that vital information.  It will likely be contained within a folder within `C:\Program Files\Java\ `provided it's a 64-bit version of Java

Answer (score 1):

The Minecraft launcher ships with its own Java version. It's located where the launcher is installed. For me it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\runtime\jre-x64\bin`